# How can I accommodate things in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

im trying to learn python and i thought on make a piano,
i started to create it with tkinter, but i dont find the way to arrange the buttons like a piano
this is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("360x240")

label1 = tk.Label()
label1['text'] = "Piano"
label1.pack()


btn_C = tk.Button(ventana, text='C', width=3, height=10)
btn_C.pack()

btn_Db = tk.Button(ventana, text='Db', width=3, height=10)
btn_Db.pack()

btn_E = tk.Button(ventana, text='E', width=3, height=10)
btn_E.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

I also thought that I could create all the buttons with a loop or something like that, if someone could explain me how I would appreciate it very much.

English is not my language, sorry if there is any mistake :p

Comment: What do you get currently, and what do you expect to get?

Comment: Use `grid()` for better flexibility.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 at this moment i only want to create a holizontal line with 12 buttons

Comment: @CoolCloud I already tried with it but i dont understand the usage very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be adding the items using a for loop with `side=tk.LEFT` option of `.pack`

```
l=['C','Dd','E']
for b in l:
    btn_b = tk.Button(ventana, text=b, width=3, height=10).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

or even one line as

```
btn_b = [ tk.Button(ventana, text=b, width=3, height=10).pack(side=tk.LEFT) for b in ['C','Dd','E'] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want all the buttons on the same horizontal line. This should get you what you want.

```
import tkinter as tk
ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("360x240")

label1 = tk.Label()
label1['text'] = "Piano"
label1.pack()

btn_C = tk.Button(ventana, text='C', width=3, height=10)
btn_C.pack(side='left')

btn_Db = tk.Button(ventana, text='Db', width=3, height=10)
btn_Db.pack(side='left')

btn_E = tk.Button(ventana, text='E', width=3, height=10)
btn_E.pack(side='left')

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: yay!! yes i want to do something like that